# What is the cost of using external libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is some front-end web development libraries that is most commonly used:

- [jquery-min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js) (95.9 kB)
- [angular.min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js) (108.0 kB)
- [bootstrap.min.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.1/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist.zip) (113.5 kB)
- bootstrap-theme.min.css (19.8 kB)
- bootstrap-fonts (185.7 kB)
- bootstrap.min.js (35.6 kB)

All together, this means `+ 558.5 kB` to every page of our website. And few more server requests. So, is that all? Are there some more (performance or other) costs of using external libraries on our website?

Comment: I guess that's why one of the reasons why [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) exists.

Comment: Is this meant to be an actual question?

Comment: Most of the time, a users' browser will cache your scripts, so, the additional 558.5 kb you mention doesn't always come into play. If you host the libraries, there's at least a cost involved on the first page visit. If you use the libraries that are hosted on Google's CDN, for example, it's possible the libraries are *already* cached IF the user has visited some other site prior to yours where those libraries were utilized.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I wouldn't bundle external libraries.

Comment: @ZippyV obviously, but it's an alternative to CDNs which reduce the size of the requested page.

Answer (score 2):

Each library you include has both costs and benefits throughout the stack

#### Costs

- time/latency (performance) to load and render
- bandwidth to serve to clients, bandwidth to deploy if bundled
- build time and file size if you are bundling these into your deployment package
- complexity to understand, modify, debug
- complexity required to prove that a given CSS rule is in fact not involved
- memory to load into your page

#### Benefits

- generally more correct and complete implementations (like bootstrap's accessibility)
- re-use of existing solutions, shorter development time
- guided toward consistent structures and away from ad-hoc messes
- better and easier APIs (vanilla XHR vs $http.get, etc)

Given your specific examples, in general if you are using angular you should not need jQuery and should avoid it. You can also cherry-pick only the portions of bootstrap your site actually uses or only the ui.bootstrap angular directives you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, that 558.5kB only hits a maximum of 1 time (as long as you don't change domains or change SSL encryption between sites). After those files are first downloaded, it's on the client to load them from the cache.

As @Felix Kling suggested, if you pull them from a CDN, it's very likely you can turn that 1-time hit to a 0-time hit because the client already downloaded them from some other website. This is important to think about if you're considering baking in the bootstrap css with your custom css file. It could be faster to let bootstrap come from the CDN (or the local cache) and load your custom stuff on top.

Performance for snagging the files won't be that big of a deal, as modern browsers have no problems quickly pulling 6 files. However, the browser has to load all that junk into memory, which is where the real hit comes in. This is because, for instance, you have to load jquery before you can call jquery. Therefore, all your on-page scripts are going to be waiting for jquery to load until they act.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is hard to say anything tangible, however using libraries is usually a tradeoff between the ease of development and performance. Some of the libraries may perform worse, than "native" JavaScript solutions, but provide more easily maintainable code.

So it is useful to test the website for potential bottlenecks in the JavaScript code, sometimes there is a valid reason to fall back to vanilla JavaScript, instead of higher level abstractions (and nicer code).

Another result of using JavaScript libraries can be, that the website will no longer function without disable JavaScript at all - this should be considered sometimes.

PS: One simple optimization is putting all JavaScript into a bundle, and minimizing it to reach the lowest possible load cost. CDNs should be also considered.